# Codename One: detect "caps lock" key

Tags: codenameone

In Codename One, is there a way to detect if the "Caps Lock" key is active (and to listen to its activation or deactivation), at the purpose to show a warning in a login Form (to prevent wrong typing of password)?

Of course this question is referred to the contexts in which it makes sense, that means: Simulator, Desktop ports, Javascript ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have such an API but I'm guessing it could be added. You can also check if all the letters are upper case and use that as a heuristic.